Find occurrence of YYYYmmDD date in variable string
Suppose I have a string containing dates in YYYYmmDD format but in variable position and containing also other numeric sequences
For example:
xx12x20240113yyyy123zzzz
20240201xxxx34yyy
xxxxxx202400315yyy1224zzz

Is there a simple way to find and extract the date sequence of numers or should I try to read all sequences thru a loop and test them one by one?
At the moment, I'm using a loop but I'd like to find a more elegant way.
This is what I'm using at the moment:
    private bool InvoiceData(string Filename, out string Invoice, out String InvoiceDate, out string Error)
    {
        bool Esito = false;
        Invoice = "";
        InvoiceDate = "";
        Error = "";

        try 
        {
            int nPos = 0;
            int nPos2 = 0;
            string sTemp = Filename;
            string sTemp2 = "";

            while ((nPos = sTemp.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray())) >= 0)
            {
                sTemp2 = sTemp.Substring(nPos, 8);
                if (sTemp2.All(char.IsNumber))
                {
                    string[] formats = { "yyyyMMdd" };
                    if (InvoiceDate == "" && DateTime.TryParseExact(sTemp2, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dDataFattura))
                    {
                        InvoiceDate = dDataFattura.ToString("yyyMMdd");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Invoice == "")
                    {
                        nPos2 = sTemp.Substring(nPos).IndexOf("_");     // This is by Design
                        Invoice = Filename.Substring(nPos, nPos2);
                    }
                }

                nPos2 = 0;
                while (Char.IsDigit(sTemp2[nPos2++]) && nPos2 < sTemp2.Length) { }
                sTemp = sTemp.Substring(nPos + nPos2);
            }
            if (InvoiceDate != "" && Invoice != "") { Esito = true; }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex.Message;
        }
        return Esito; 
    }


Have you tried a regular expression? Check for example Regex to validate date formats or yyyy-mm-dd Date format

what exactly did you mean by saying or should I try to read all sequences thru a loop and test them one by one? which kind of loop? and what's the target? is just one string? what are you looping over? As suggested above.. you can just use a regex to match that YYYYMMDD pattern

What if the "other numeric sequences" also look like dates?

You'll have to validate all matches because a regular expression can't detect leap years. 20230229 isn't a valid date for example. What does the actual data look like? You may be able to use the text surrounding a date to detect whether you have a date or a phone number that starts with 202

If the expected dates are surrounded by whitespace or non-word characters for example you could use \W(?<date>\d{8})\W or \b(?<date>\d{8})\b to capture the date in a group named date.

I suggest using regular expressions to obtain raw matches which we validate with DateTime.TryParseExact. Since we are going to have a collection of matches, Linq can be very convenient:
Having
string text =
@"xx12x20240113yyyy123zzzz
20240201xxxx34yyy
xxxxxx202400315yyy1224zzz";

We can put
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var result = Regex
  .Matches(text, "[0-9]{8}") // raw match - 8 digits (e.g. 12345678)
  .Where(match => DateTime.TryParseExact( // match validation - must be date
                    match.Value,
                   "yyyyMMdd",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                    out var date) && 
     date.Year >= 1950 && date.Year <= 2050) // we don't want year 4000th and alike
  .Select(match => match.Value);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));

Output:
20240113
20240201

Please, fiddle yourself

Nice solution, but what is the point of DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal?

@Good Night Nerd Pride: As for DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, I filter date to be within the range (better say, show how can one do it); I think using local date makes it easier for OP to implement his/her own filter.

There are a few options, but this sort of thing is what Regular Expressions were created for.
This can be as simple or as complex as you want, but it's still not going to work for all possible dates. 20230229 isn't a valid date, while 20240229 is valid. While we could write an incredibly complex regex to properly handle leap days, it'd be a terrible idea.
We could also craft a slightly less complex solution that narrows the field down to mostly valid dates, with the exception that some invalid leap days will pass the initial filter. Something like this (split and spaced, use IgnoreWhitespace to use this):
(?<year>\d{4})
(?:
    (?<month>02)(?<day>0[1-9]|[12][0-9])|
    (?<month>0[469]|11)(?<day>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|
    (?<month>0[123578]|1[02])(?<day>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
)

While this works for a lot of possible good dates, it also includes invalid leap days. The only way to figure this is to try to parse the output to see if the returned date string is in fact valid.
But since we're going to have to do that anyway, why not make this simple?
The simplest form (as Panagiotis commented) is to search for a string of 8 digits (\d{8}). This will capture all valid dates and a lot of invalid ones, which you can then parse to find the ones that match an actual date value.
Here's an example:
static readonly Regex EightDigits = new(@"\d{8}");

static IEnumerable<DateTime> FindDates(string source)
{
    foreach (Match match in EightDigits.Matches(source))
    {
        // Add some '-'s between the date parts. Makes parsing easier.
        string matched = match.Value;
        string parseText = string.Join('-', [matched[0..4], matched[4..6], matched[6..8]]);

        // Check if we can parse the date correctly.
        if (DateTime.TryParse(parseText, out DateTime date))
            yield return date;
    }
}

Now let's apply that to your sample string:
const string TestSource = @"xx12x20240113yyyy123zzzz
20240201xxxx34yyy
xxxxxx202400315yyy1224zzz";

foreach (DateTime date in FindDates(TestSource))
    Console.WriteLine($"{date:yyyy-MM-dd}");

Output:
2024-01-13
2024-02-01

Note that it didn't return 20240031 due to the double 0 there causing DateTime.TryParse to fail. And it didn't try to find another option in that block of numbers, because it doesn't know how to anticipate that as a necessity. We could adapt by having it return all strings of numbers with at least 8 digits and working through them ourselves, but that seems wasteful.

The issue with this is that it will fail to locate otherwise valid dates that have other numbers around them. That's when the more interesting variant will help:
// Packed form of the regex above.
static readonly Regex DateRE = new(@"(?<year>\d{4})(?:(?<month>02)(?<day>0[1-9]|[12][0-9])|(?<month>0[469]|11)(?<day>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(?<month>0[123578]|1[02])(?<day>0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))");

static IEnumerable<DateTime> FindDates2(string source)
{
    foreach (Match match in DateRE.Matches(source))
    {
        // We can pull the named parts out of this regex match.
        string parseText = string.Join('-', [match.Groups["year"].Value, match.Groups["month"], match.Groups["day"]]);

        if (DateTime.TryParse(parseText, out DateTime date))
            yield return date;
    }
}

const string OtherTestSource =  @"xx12x20240113yyyy123zzzz
20240201xxxx34yyy
xxxxxx202400315yyy1224zzz
12020240409999";

Running the same kind of output loop on the results gives us:
2024-01-13
2024-02-01
0240-03-15
2024-04-09

That 0240-03-15 date seems a little out of place there though, so you may want to do some additional refinement of your RE (such as ensuring the first digit is a 1 or 2, followed by 3 other digits) or add a range check to the value. Just remember that matches are greedy and it won't return multiple offset matches from the same block of numbers, no matter how well they work.

If you want to reliably validate  8-chars-sections in a string to actually represent true date values, DateTime.TryParseExact is likely the appropriate tool in .NET.
If you're just after some rough validation making sure you have an 8-decimal-digit sequence, a regex or char.IsDigit will suffice.
    string [] lines =
    { 
       "xx12x20240113yyyy123zzzz",
       "20240201xxxx34yyy", 
       "xxxxxx202400315yyy1224zzz", 
       "20100925"
    };
    
    foreach (var date in ExtractDates(lines, "yyyyMMdd"))
        Console.Write("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} ", date);

    // 2024-01-13 2024-02-01 0240-03-15 2010-09-25
    


IEnumerable<DateTime> ExtractDates(IEnumerable<string> lines, string datePattern)
{
    foreach (var line in lines) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= line.Length - datePattern.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(line, i) && DateTime.TryParseExact(line.Substring(i, datePattern.Length), datePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateMatch))
            {
                yield return dateMatch;
                i += datePattern.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}

